# Adafruit BNO055 orientation sensor

Tags: stm32, embedded, keil, adafruit

My sensor is a [BNO055](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor/overview) Absolute Orientation Sensor.

I wanted to see if the sensor is ready or not. I tried to run it using different libraries, but it never worked. I couldn't understand why. Then I wanted to test if the sensor was ready with the I2C protocol. At this point in my work, I saw that my sensor never came to the ready state.

Connections:

SDA_pin -> SDA pin sensor
SCL_pin -> SCL pin sensor
5V -> VCC
GND -> GND

ADR -> GND

PS0 -> GND

PS1 -> GND

I use I2C with my STM32F401RE.

```
------MX_I2C3_Init()-----------
hi2c3.Instance = I2C3;
hi2c3.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
hi2c3.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
hi2c3.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
hi2c3.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
hi2c3.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
hi2c3.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
----------------------------

void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c) {
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if (hi2c->Instance == I2C3) {
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* I2C3 GPIO Configuration
    PC9     ------> I2C3_SDA
    PA8     ------> I2C3_SCL
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C3;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C3;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_I2C3_CLK_ENABLE();
  }

  while (!ready) {
    if (HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c3, (0x28 << 1), 10, 1000) == HAL_OK) {
      // BNO055 is ready, perform additional initialization
      ready = 1;
    } else if (HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c3 ,(0x29 << 1), 10, 1000) == HAL_OK) {
      ready = 2;
    }       
    else {
      // BNO055 is not ready yet, wait and try again
      HAL_Delay(100);
    }
```

It never goes into `HAL_OK` state.
I tried with the ADR pin connected to VCC or GND, but nothing changes.

**----EDİT----**

Tried I2C scan but not work.(for find divice address) [I2C_Scan](https://deepbluembedded.com/stm32-i2c-scanner-hal-code-example/)

I performed an I2C scan on a different sensor [mpu6050](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf) using the same pins and it was successful.
I don't think it's an issue with my mcu.

Comment: You didn't include your actual circuit or full code. It is quite difficult to guess at the all the possible problems with such minimal information. Did you try the original setup and code example on the All info page (single page) Adafruit site: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor?view=all

Comment: Yes I tried but it didn't work. Right now i just want to see its sensor ready and that's my code for it.

Comment: If seems you're doing your own I2C setups, are you sure you set the correct address for the module? (0x28, 0x29).  I see two address setups in your code but no idea what they are.  There is an Adafruit customer support forum - you might try asking there for more direct info.  See:  https://forums.adafruit.com/

Comment: Adress about adr pin vcc or gnd. I already posted there

Comment: @LOODAN  -  Did you try the Bosch-Library? (https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BNO055_driver)

Comment: Do you have physical pull-ups on your I2C lines. What is their value? What is the level of the SCL and SDA line if no communication takes place? It appears that your communication fails completely.

Comment: @MikroPower have a nice day, yes I tried.

Comment: @TomL. good morning. I dont know what value but i tried same pins with other sensor (mcu6050) and it works. I think something about bno055.

Comment: @LOODAN - Is PS0 and PS1 on the BNO055 module connected to GND? On the original Board it is connected to GND over 10k Ohm, but possibly you are using a Chinese copy?

Comment: @MikroPower sensor not copy but i connected PS0 and PS1 to gnd.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the bus in MSPinit function. That function is called by I2Cinit to initialize the IO subsystem before initializing the I2C peripheral. So you did not bother to check what the error code returned from the function was, other than it's not OK.

Likely it still does not work because is that the chip looks like it will not respond to protocol used by IsDeviceReady.

The data sheet of the chip does not indicate that you can do a read without writing a register value first.

After initializing the IO pins and I2C properly, try reading the Device ID register instead. If that succeeds, chip works on the bus. If it doesn't, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for answer ,first i read device ıd but not success